# ConnectionString Exception After Installing WebService

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, database-connection

I have a webservice that I am using to get information from users. Before installing the service, it works fine. After installing the service, I am getting an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." The WCF is referencing a dll where validating and writing to the database and return the results. The dll library has an app config where I added the connection string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="reqInformation" connectionString="Data Source=databasesourceInitial Catalog=databasename;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I have this class that is getting the connection string

```
public abstract class BASEClass
    {
        public static string GetConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["reqInformation"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }
    }
```

I added the same connection string to the wcf config file. 
In addition, I added a test project to test the service before installing it, it worked fine. I installed the WCF Service and ran the test project again, and it failed. The exception was Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app config was added to the service Library; however, the service library was not the executing assembly. As a result, it was giving that exception. I moved the connection string int he executing assembly, recompile the code, re-install the service, and test it. All things are working as expected.